# Grouping My Leg Workouts

Tags: legs

Calves, Hamstrings, Quads, Glutes...

I have two days to exercise each group.  As far as weights go, how would you group these exercises?  Calves/Hamstrings on one day, Quads/Glutes on the other?  There will be rest for these muscle groups between days.

Thanks for the help.  Please note your reasoning.

Comment: What's your current program? What are your goals?

Comment: Don't necessarily discount the effectiveness of compound workouts which target multiple of these muscles at once. Personally I do Squats, Deadlifts, and Power Cleans to hit my legs. Since they are compound, though, it may be tough to figure out which split leg workout to put them in.

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct way answer this question; as the answer would depend on your approach to weightlifting.

The best advice I can honestly give is "don't overthink it".

Generally speaking: As long as you do the right selection of exercises correctly and with enough intensity, results will follow.

Look at how developed a powerlifter's legs are, great example that exercise grouping is not necessary.